# How to find out which color is used when button is hovered?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to find out which color is used when button is hovered in WinForms?

I created a button and set some color to BackColor. If mouse is entering the button's area, button's color will be changed to lighter color, and then it will be changed back to my color when mouse left button's area. I want to catch that color. How can I do this?

How is it working internally?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ButtonName.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(Button_MouseHover);
//...
private void Button_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    varbtn = sender as Button;
    var your_color = btn.BackColor;
}
```

Also, you can use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events to change color.

Comment: I tried to this but it shows me the same color that I set in properties for BackColor on all this events (MouseEnter, MouseHover and MouseLeave)